# Show marker infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

In onMapReady I am defining a few markers

First I declare the marker and his icon that is common for all markers and then each marker with it's own attributes. The problem is that when I declare the marker I cannot declare it as `Marker beerMarker = new Marker()` options as it makes me cast the Marker into `MarkerOptions`. What I would like is to call the info window for every marker but I cant as the `beerMarker.showInfoWindow()` is not acceptable for MarkerOptions. What am I doing wrong and what are the alternatives?

```
 MarkerOptions beerMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker));

 //Carciuma
        LatLng carciuma = new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(carciuma).title("Carciuma"));
        //Boca
        LatLng boca = new LatLng(43.604496, 1.474924);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(boca).title("Boca"));
        //Bar Acasa
        LatLng barAcasa = new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);
        mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(barAcasa).title("Bar Acasa"));
```

Here is the updated version of the marker that meens I have t have to add for every individual marker the same icon, no?

```
LatLng barAcasa = new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);
    Marker beerMarkerAcasa = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(barAcasa)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
            .title("Bar Acasa"));
    beerMarkerAcasa.showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this way `Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markeroption);`

you can pass marker option for particulate marker in addMarker() method, they return marker instance which you can use.

Comment: I know that I can do it like that, but I wanted to define the marker's common characteristics only once (like icon and info window). The way that you are saying I have to specify the showInfoWindow and the icon  for every marker that I add, no? This way the code will look like the updated example and I would have to have a different marker name for every marker, no?

Comment: LatLng barAcasa = new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);
        Marker beerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(barAcasa)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .title("Bar Acasa"));
        beerMarker.showInfoWindow(); My review is pending .....

Comment: You can also create a Builder for MarkerOptions so you can build several MarkerOptions changing only the parameters needed for each one